# How to display facebook payments in real currency with pay dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook pay dialog with action buy_items... i implemented the callback url and everything works correctly. In "payments_get_items" callback i set "price" property to (for example ) 5 (meaning 5 US dollars), but it seems that facebook understands this as 5 credits which is priced as $1.5 (or some other value different from $5). I don't want to display credits in my pay dialog but in client's local currency.
I am not sure how to do this.. 
Note: I didn't register company yet (may be this is the problem?)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/28/pricing-in-a-user-s-preferred-currency/ + https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/28/pricing-in-a-user-s-preferred-currency/

Comment: I already use oscif=true, but the problem here is that i have to fixate  the credits amount as value for some item instead of fixating the value in real currency.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/callback/ price should be set in Facebook Credits:

> The product cost based in credits. All product costs must be based in
>   credits. Integer value must be > 0.

Indeed using dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true} will instruct Facebook to display the price in the user preferred currency instead of Facebook Credits. You don't need to register a company to get this working.

I think your issue is to convert USD to Facebook Credits (correct me if I'm wrong). Currently a Facebook credit is worth 0.10 USD, $1.00 USD = 10 Facebook Credits (http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=204417036262972)

Note that you can also convert currencies to Facebook Credits and the opposite using this tool: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/user_currency/ This will allow you to display the exact value in USD, EUR...